# Rational Coordinates with two intersecting lines.

Tags: coordinate-systems, rational-numbers, intersection-theory, slope

If there are two 2D lines with rational slopes that intersect, must the intersection point have rational co-ordinates?

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this and not sure how you prove it?

Comment: If the equation of the line is written in the form $y=mx+c$ , then I think the point of intersection will be dependent on the value of $c$.

Comment: @tcheny3 Use squared graph paper. Sketch a few line pairs between square corners and observe the paired line intersections.

Comment: Wait, you duplicated your own question?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $y=ax+b$ and $y=cx+d$, then $ax+b=cx+d$.